# Desktop WPF application deployment on cloud

Tags: .net, wpf, hosting, cloud

I have spent a long time building a desktop WPF application using .NET, and instead of packaging it in CDs I am looking to deploy it on a cloud so that multiple users can use it, and so that it would be easier for me to patch it in one place only.  Is this possible?  I really don't want change the entire code so that it is for web browsers. Are there any tricks I can use.  I know Windows Azure has remote desktop option.  Would I be able to use that.  Any other options?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at ClickOnce?

Comment: This is a pretty general question -- you might want to provide more specifics about your application and the user community. Also see the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidance. Your questions are welcome here, but more specific questions are likely to get more specific responses.

Comment: Agree with @CoryNelson, ClickOnce is your best bet. Remote desktopping (is that even a word?) :P is going to deteriorate the User Experience, which I'm sure is really spectacular if you did it in WPF.

Comment: You need to read up on deployment.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa969776(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend looking at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx) is a guide on how to publish through the wizard in Visual Studio.

If you wish to host in a cloud service such as Azure, you can do that also with ClickOnce by hosting the bundle in Azure Storage, check out instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/09/how-to-deploy-clickonce-application-using-windows-azure-storage-in-very-simple-steps.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can try
 [XBaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)
or
the [Roozz plugin](http://www.roozz.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to deploy it on cloud then I will recommend Amazon cloud services(AWS). It has a free tier which is available for a year. It also provides you with a SDK for .NET and a toolkit for Visual Studio for ease of migration to cloud. For details try these links

http://aws.amazon.com/net/

http://aws.amazon.com/free/